# find the closest point using orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In the example [below](https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math54Fa11/Homeworks/Homework%207%20-%20Solutions.pdf), how would we have solved it if $v_1$ and $v_2$ were not orthogonal?

[image]

Note: the second term above should be $\frac{x \cdot v_2}{v_2 \cdot v_2}v_2$

Comment: Now I see what’s bothering you: $v_1\cdot v_2$ in the denominator in your Solution... This is a typo, it should be $v_2\cdot v_2$, and that is how it is calculated further on...

Comment: seems this should have v2.v2 in the second denominator and the answer is wrong in the screenshot (in terms of formula not the real answer).

Comment: Indeed... This should’ve rang bells, as in your example $v_1$ and $v_2$ *are* orthogonal, so you would expect to see division by zero in the very next step... which didn’t happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case one would use [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to make them orthogonal. Then follow the solution using the found set of orthogonal vectors.

Let's say $v_1=(1,0,0,0)$ and $v_2=(1,1,0,0)$. These are not orthogonal, but we can take $u_1=v_1$ and $u_2=v_2-{\langle u_1, v_2\rangle\over\langle u_1, u_1\rangle}{u_1}=(1,1,0,0)-\frac{1}{1}(1,0,0,0)=(0,1,0,0)$, where $\langle u, v\rangle$ denotes the dot product of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: is there a step by step example you can provide?

Comment: well, this makes me confused. I have v1=(1, 1, 0)T and v2=(0, 1, 1)T and I am caculating the closest the distance of v3=(1, 1, 1)T from orthogonal projection of v3 onto the span of v1 and v2 denoted by a*v1+b*v2 however, in the photo I uploaded, we have v1.v2 in the denominator. Which after making v1.v2' orthogonal it would be zero. What should I do?

Comment: @MonaJalal It cannot be zero, as $v_3$ is not in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$. You probably made a calculation error somewhere in your Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: can you confirm that we will have v1+2v2' for the numbers I gave using the screenshot?

Comment: @MonaJalal I get $u_1=(1,1,0)$ and $u_2=(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$ from the $v_1$ and $v_2$ you gave in your comment. Now the picture can be repeated using these $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: actually my final answer is v1+2/3v2

Comment: @MonaJalal Gram-Schmidt gives me $u_2=v_1-\frac{1}{2}v_2$...

Comment: ok seems I am totally confused. I thought first we use gram-schmidt to make them orthogonal and then we use the one in screenshot. Am I wrong? see here https://imgur.com/a/lxWf9

Comment: @MonaJalal Ah yes, *the final answer* is indeed $v_1+\frac{2}{3}v_2$. I thought we were talking about $u_2$ the whole time :)

Comment: ok cool thanks for confirming I was right. I was going to believe I am wrong in mixing the two :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72369/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-the-phenotype).

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to write $x=y+\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2$, with $y\bot v_1,v_2$. Do the dot product of this with $v_1$ and $v_2$:

$$x\cdot v_1=(v_1\cdot v_1)\alpha_1+(v_2\cdot v_1)\alpha_2$$
$$x\cdot v_2=(v_1\cdot v_2)\alpha_1+(v_2\cdot v_2)\alpha_2$$

Now solve on $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$.

**Note**: The following formula would come as a result of using the Cramer’s rule to solve the system, then replacing $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$:

$$x-y=\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}x\cdot v_1 & v_2\cdot v_1\\ x\cdot v_2 & v_2\cdot v_2\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix}v_1\cdot v_1 & v_2\cdot v_1\\ v_1\cdot v_2 & v_2\cdot v_2\end{matrix}\right|}v_1+ \frac{\left|\begin{matrix}v_1\cdot v_1 & x\cdot v_1\\ v_1\cdot v_2 & x\cdot v_2\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix}v_1\cdot v_1 & v_2\cdot v_1\\ v_1\cdot v_2 & v_2\cdot v_2\end{matrix}\right|}v_2 $$

It simplifies to your formula if $v_1\cdot v_2=0$. (Note the typo in your formula - should have $v_2\cdot v_2$ instead of $v_1\cdot v_2$.)